# Practically implementing scoring rules

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scoring-rules

I am intrigued by the discussion of [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules) yet I am left wondering about its practical implementation; I hope this thread can ameliorate that for me and ideally others. Tabling the issue of the forecast combination puzzle, I am interested in the application of scoring rules with respect to stacking methods, discussed here: [Ensemble classifiers trained using different sets of features](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583930/ensemble-classifiers-trained-using-different-sets-of-features)

Let's say we have a trivial example of the following: two models trained on different features and we are convinced that stacking would be a great idea. Instead of training yet another model, we can use scoring rules -- but how?

What does our next steps look like? Are the steps the same even if we have two different models trained on different features (assuming we end up with predicted probabilities after training with both models)?

Separately but relatedly -- what **should** I be doing after getting predicted probabilities to use my scoring function properly/in practice?

````
# a MWE to get started
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

# load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# first model; first 2 features
m1 = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg').fit(iris.data[:, :2], iris.target)
# preds
m1_preds = np.round(m1.predict_proba(X), decimals=4)

# second model; last 2 features
m2 = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg').fit(iris.data[:, 2:], iris.target)
# preds
m2_preds = np.round(m2.predict_proba(X), decimals=4)

# gen scores
m1_score = log_loss(iris.target, m1_preds)
m2_score = log_loss(iris.target, m2_preds)
```
````

Comment: I have to admit that I don't fully understand what your question is. Per [the current answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/610962/1352), the question of how to combine or stack models or predictions is separate from how to evaluate the stacked model, or the constituent models - the two aspects are pretty much independent. As to your last paragraph, once you have your probabilistic predictions and the corresponding observations, you plug them into the scoring rule and hope for low values (or high ones, depending on your convention). Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: I am interested in all of the above! Thanks for your time and consideration

Answer (score 1):

How you combine different model forecasts is your own decision and has nothing to do with scoring rules, just like it wouldn't have anything to do with accuracy. You obtain multiple forecasts (whether they be probabilistic forecasts or "classifications"), you then combine them somehow (for ex. simple average), and then you use these with your scoring rule (or classification metric) of choice. So in a sense it's the same as using only one model results, it is your job (and a separate task) to combine multiple forecasts.